# Displaying multipe Array-type attributes of sharedObject.data property in a single list

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have various food category pages (such as "Carbohyrates", "Meat", "Vegetables" etc) that have 3 comboboxes on each page where a user can select 3 different ingredients from each category (i.e. on the "Meat" page, a user can select 3 different types of meat). I write these 3 meats to a sharedObject as an Array like so:

Here is my `saveMeat()` function as an example so you can understand how I am forming my arrays:

```
function saveMeat(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _categoryMeat.btn_goback.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveMeat);
    removeChild(_categoryMeat);

    if (meatDisableCheckBox.selected == true)
    {
        stop();
    } 

    if (myComboBoxMeat.selectedLabel != null)
    {
        so.data.meat1 = myComboBoxMeat.selectedLabel;
        trace(so.data.meat1);
    }
    if (myComboBoxMeat2.selectedLabel != null)
    {
        so.data.meat2 = myComboBoxMeat2.selectedLabel;
        trace(so.data.meat2);
    }
    if (myComboBoxMeat3.selectedLabel != null)
    {
        so.data.meat3 = myComboBoxMeat3.selectedLabel;
        trace(so.data.meat3);
    } 
    var meat_items_array:Array = new Array(so.data.meat1, so.data.meat2, so.data.meat3);
    so.data.meatItems = meat_items_array;
    so.flush();
    trace(so.data.meatItems);
}
```

There are several of these functions for each of the category pages (in all 6 different functions). They are all pretty similiar except for the fact the checkboxes and comboboxes differ.

I have a list function called `dataLoaded` that loads items from the sharedObject into the scrolling list:

```
private function dataLoaded():void
{
    var i:Number;
    for (i=0;  i < so.data.meatItems.length; i++) {
        _item = new Item();
        // creates the var itemTextField //
        _itemTextField = new TextField();
        _itemTextField.text += '' + so.data.meatItems[i].toString();
        //adds textfield to displaylist//
        _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop inputs the `toString()` representation of one of my attributes of my sharedObject (`so.data.meatItems`) into the `TextField` but I want to input all instances inside of my sharedObject no matter what sub-attribute they have. Also notice that I'm evaluating the `length` of the `meatItems` array in the `for` loop conditional, when I would want to be evaluating all items in the `sharedObject`

How can I do this?

EDIT: I implemented the below solution but am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at RecipeMatcher/dataLoaded()[/Users/adambull/Desktop/RecipeMatcherSO/RecipeMatcher.as:893]
    at RecipeMatcher/displayList()[/Users/adambull/Desktop/RecipeMatcherSO/RecipeMatcher.as:212]
    at RecipeMatcher/hideSplashScreen()[/Users/adambull/Desktop/RecipeMatcherSO/RecipeMatcher.as:192]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at SetIntervalTimer/onTimer()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Here is my attempt at implementing the below (I have included my full function this time just in case there is something else in my function causing problems)

```
private function dataLoaded():void
{
    // parsing of each ingredient//
    // instantiation of mcItem (the stage for each item)
    for (var item:* in so.data)
    {
        if (so.data[item] !=null)
        {
            if (so.data[item] is Array)
            {
                var a:Array = so.data[item];
                for (var i:uint = 0 ; i < a.length;i++ )
                {
                    _item = new Item();
                    // sets //over// layer to invisible / transparent //
                    _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
                    // creates the var itemTextField //
                    _itemTextField = new TextField();
                    // _itemTextField visual attributes //
                    _itemTextField.x = _textFieldXPosition + _textFieldPaddingLeft;
                    _itemTextField.y = _textFieldYPosition;
                    _itemTextField.selectable = true;
                    _itemTextField.wordWrap = true;
                    itemTextField.width = _textFieldWidth;
                    _itemTextField.height = _textFieldHeight;
                    _itemTextField.embedFonts = true;
                    _defaultFormat.color = 0x111112;
                    _defaultFormat.font = _arialRounded.fontName;
                    _defaultFormat.size = 18;
                    _itemTextField.defaultTextFormat = _defaultFormat;
                    _itemTextField.appendText( so.data[item][i].toString() );
                    //adds textfield to displaylist//
                    _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
                    //vertical positioning//
                    _item.y = i * _itemPosition;
                    _item.btn_delete.visible = false;
                    _item.buttonMode = true;
                    _item.mouseChildren = false;
                    //adds items to container displaylist//
                    _container.addChild(_item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Input Mask//
    _mask = new Shape();
    _mask.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    _mask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _maskWidth, _maskHeight);
    _mask.graphics.endFill();
    // Positioning of input mask//
    // horizontal centering of input mask//
    _mask.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
    _mask.y = _paddingTop;
    // adds the mask onto the stage//
    addChild(_mask);
    // assigns the above mask to the container //
    _container.mask = _mask;
    // Positioning of container with the mask//
    // horizontal centering of container //
    _container.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _container.width / 2;
    // vertical position of container //
    _container.y = _paddingTop;

    //Container background stylings//
    _background = new Shape();

    _background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _container.width, _container.height);

    _container.addChildAt(_background, 0);
    //End of container background stylings//
    _item.parent.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked );
    _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, movingOver);
    _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, movingOut);
}
```

(I have tried adding an extra `if` to evaluate whether the content of each shared object attribute is empty or not - because I believe that if an array is empty this may cause another error?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you question, here is an example. It browse so.data, looks for arrays and then iterates on each one.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var my_so = SharedObject.getLocal("superfoo");
// fill some fake values
var ar:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var ar2:Array = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
my_so.data.array1 = ar;
my_so.data.array2 = ar2;
my_so.data.notarray = 'I m not an array';
my_so.flush();


// browse the so and find arrays
var my_so2 = SharedObject.getLocal("superfoo");
for (var item:* in my_so2.data) {       
    if (my_so2.data[item] is Array) {
        var a:Array = my_so2.data[item];
        for(var i:uint = 0 ; i<a.length;i++ ) {
            trace('my_so2.data[' + item + '][' + i + ']=' + a[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput (it skips items that are not Arrays in so.data)

```
my_so2.data[array2][0]=a1
my_so2.data[array2][1]=a2
my_so2.data[array2][2]=a3
my_so2.data[array2][3]=a4
my_so2.data[array1][0]=1
my_so2.data[array1][1]=2
my_so2.data[array1][2]=3
my_so2.data[array1][3]=4
my_so2.data[array1][4]=5
```

Comment: Yes, you did understand my question correctly. Unfortunately, when I implement your code, it gives me "Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties." on line 891 which is the `_itemTextField.appendText...` line?

Comment: Still getting the same error, ill update my question with the stack trace + my latest implementation of your solution

Comment: do you see what you want if you remove all your display code and just trace so.data[item][i].toString()  in the loop ?